# J2ME Location Based services

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I am planning on developing a J2ME application which provide location based services but as i required i need both location determination Using **GPS** and Non GPS towers to determine location.

Is this possible in J2ME development to use network based location determination and how ?

Also im planning on using a web service which returns `JSON` will i be able to maniupate this data in J2ME environment and how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to determine location through J2ME. It is performed by the JSR-179 API. You can find an explanation of this API in the [Nokia's Java Developer's Library](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp) under the section "Developer's Guide" -> "Location Services"

How to retrieve network-based location (also called cellsite location) depends on the device manufacturer. Some criteria force the cellphone to return a network-based location provider. I have the information for a few:

- [BlackBerry](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800703/How_To_-_Define_criteria_to_retrieve_a_GPS_fix.html?nodeid=1123135&vernum=0): Not required horizontal or vertical accuracy. Cost allowed and low power consumption.
- [Nokia](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-117EE706-8EAB-474B-BB8B-81A65466B0E0.html): For S40 series, the Location API is extended with the `com.nokia.mid.location.LocationUtil` class that allows GPS device selection. For S60 user selection under "Connectivity" menu is used, except "No cost" criteria is set. JSR-179 just required that when "No cost" is set, internal GPS technology must be used.

An option I once heard about but never used or tried to implement for cellsite location is Navizon API http://www.navizon.com/businesses.php